# How to use REST API with java to update job configuration?

Tags: java, jenkins, configuration, jenkins-api

I want to update jenkins job without restarting the jenkins. For that I am using jenkins REST API in my java code. But because of CSRF security I am not able to POST anything to jenkins URL. 
By using crumbIssuer this can be done. Can anyone help me with crumbissuer ?

Answer (score 0):

To use Rest api to update the job of a CSRF secured jenkins, we need to issue a crumb. To issue crumb the following rest api is used:
http://hostname:port/crumbIssuer/api/json

it will return a jason having 3 key value pairs : 
_class
crumb
crumbRequestField

Set request header for post as crumbRequestField and the value as crumb.
Then it will be able to connect.